# Sponsorship - On the front or back cover?

Tags: design-principles

I'm publishing a small (~12 page) booklet, which occasionally has a sponsor. For technical reasons, I have only two options as to where to put it, either on the front cover or on the back cover. Which would be more appropriate to put it on?

If it helps in any way, I have small ad on the back for sponsorship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, sponsoring companies are sponsoring for the *exposure* the project provides. So, any prominence you can give their branding will be favorable.

It's difficult to state definitives without seeing overall structure of the design, but my inclination would be to place it on the front cover smaller with a "sponsored by" credit.

I would actually *also* suggest the back cover in a less prominent manner if that's feasible. **However**, you state "there's an ad on the back", if so, then the back is already covered by the ad and no additional sponsor branding would be beneficial.

Comment: The ad on the back is small (~business card size). Does that make a difference (re your last point)?

Comment: Not really, if they have branding on the back, unless you have a "sponsorship" section, there may not be a need for additional branding - hard to see without seeing artwork. Although the sponsor will **never** complain that you "overused their branding".

Answer (score 0):

If they pay more, front, if they pay less, the back.

If they pay more, bigger, if they pal less, smaller.

You need to define the prices and sizes of what the sponsor need to expect.